# YouTube Analytics API Login to Multiple Accounts under single User

Tags: php, oauth, youtube, google-analytics, google-api-php-client

We are currently writing a Analytics script that pulls information from both Google Analytics and YouTube Analytics.  We are currently using oAUTH authentication.  All of the accounts are tied together by one central Google account.  The YouTube account has multiple channels attached to it.  When using oauth to authenticate against YouTube Analytics it asks you to select the primary account (which is linked to Google Analytics and delegated access from another account), or the secondary YouTube channel account.  If you oauth into the Google Analytics account, then YouTube Analytics does not work, and vice-versa.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to tell each API to associate with a separate account under the same login token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to create two seperate offline keys.  I have done this without a database connect (but could easily had a database connect added in if you replace a part of this code).  Please note that I am just learning PHP so please bare with code issues/indention issues.

In order for this to work Google must create two access tokens in two separate files.

Here is the example of the YouTube Analytics Generator (get_yt_access_token.php):

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeAnalyticsService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('YT Analytics App');
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
$client->setRedirectUri('URL/get_yt_access_token.php');
$client->setScopes(array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
));
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $myFile            = "refreshyttoken.conf";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $client->getAccessToken());
    fclose($fh);
} else {
    if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
        $auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header("Location: $auth");
    }
}
```

Notice the refreshmytoken.conf is the name of the file being generated.

Here is the example of the Google Analytics Generator (get_ga_access_token.php):

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('GA Analytics App');
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
$client->setRedirectUri('URL/get_access_token.php');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $myFile            = "refreshgatoken.conf";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $client->getAccessToken());
    fclose($fh);
} else {
    if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
        $auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header("Location: $auth");
    }
}
```

Notice the refreshgatoken.conf is the name of the file being generated.

Google Requires for Google API:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeAnalyticsService.php';
```

On these functions remember to setClientID, Secret, and RedirectUri to what is applicable to your server and Google API keys.  Also ViewID and ChannelID are intentionally left out.

Example Google Analytics Function:

```
$viewId = "ga:xxxxxxx";

function OutboundClicksweek(){
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId('');
  $client->setClientSecret('');
  $client->setRedirectUri('URL/analytics.php');
  $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');
  $client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('refreshgatoken.conf'));
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
  $start_date = $GLOBALS["start_date"];
  $end_date = new DateTime($start_date);
  $end_date->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));
  $end_date = $end_date->format('Y-m-d');
  $metrics = "ga:totalEvents";
  $dimensions = "ga:eventCategory";
  $filters = "ga:eventCategory=~Outbound Traffic";
  $optParams = array('dimensions' => $dimensions, 'filters' => $filters);
  $props = $GLOBALS["service"]->data_ga->get($GLOBALS["viewId"],$start_date,$end_date,$metrics,$optParams);
  $events=$props->totalsForAllResults['ga:totalEvents'];
  return $events;
  };
```

Example of YouTube Function:

```
$YTChannelID = "channel==xxxxxxxxx";

function YoutubeFacebookAnalytics(){
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
$client->setRedirectUri('URL/analytics.php');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'));
$client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('refreshyttoken.conf'));
$client->setUseObjects(true);
$service = new Google_YouTubeAnalyticsService($client);
  $start_date = $GLOBALS["start_date"];
  $end_date = new DateTime($start_date);
  $end_date->add(new DateInterval('P6D'));
  $end_date = $end_date->format('Y-m-d');
  $metrics = "views";
  $dimensions = "insightTrafficSourceDetail";
  $filters = "insightTrafficSourceType==EXT_URL";
  $max_results = "25";
  $sort = "-views";
  $optParams = array('dimensions' => $dimensions, 'filters' => $filters, 'max-results' => $max_results, 'sort' => $sort);
  $pages = $service->reports->query($GLOBALS['YTChannelID'], $start_date, $end_date, $metrics, $optParams);
  print_r($pages);
  };
```

Once the coding is complete, simply go to the get access token php files in your browser and login to the appropriate Google Accounts.  Then go back to your original page and you should be good to go.